# WCF service hosted in IIS returns "Safe handle has been closed" when used in different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, wcf

I'm having some problems with a wcf proxy in a winform. This wcf service is hosted on IIS, exposes 2 methods and is working as it should when I'm using it in a single thread winform (one call at a time). The problem shows up when I use the same proxy (same instance or 2 separate instances, it doesn't matter) in different threads, I do get an error : "Safe handle has been closed".

What I really don't understand is: if I start some threads that all call the same wcf method, it works fine. The problem only occurs when I start a call to one of the wcf method, start another call to the second wcf method and that this second call finishes before the first one is done. To clarify:

```
This will work:
    - start threadA that calls wcf MethodA
    - start threadB that calls wcf MethodA
    - MethodA in threadA finishes <-- No errors
    - MethodA in threadB finishes <-- No errors

This won't work:
    - start threadA that calls wcf MethodA
    - start threadB that calls wcf MethodB
    - MethodB in threadB finishes <-- No errors
    - MethodA in threadA finishes <-- Error "Safe handle has been closed"

This won't work either, methods order doesn't matter, only the fact that I mix methods it seems:
    - start threadA that calls wcf MethodB
    - start threadB that calls wcf MethodA
    - MethodA in threadB finishes <-- No errors
    - MethodB in threadA finishes <-- Error "Safe handle has been closed"
```

This is the stack that I'm receiving:

```
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyProxy.MyInterface.MyMethod(String myParam)
```

Anyone has an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, all proxy classes derive from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase. As per MSDN documentation, instance methods of ClientBase are not thread safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx

Also, looking at the error, there might be some common resource in your service. Please check if MethodA and MethodB are accessing a common resource. Debugging service will help

Comment: Well it says "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."... I tried both static and instance member with the same result. I also tried 2 separate instance members and 2 separate public static members. I still get the error.

Comment: I was assuming that the service calls will be instance methods. How did you make them static?  also, is methodA and methodB working on a common resource on the server side?

Comment: I have 2 classes, one of them is using methodA and the other one methodB so I just tried one static member per class. Even if I declare a new proxy in the scope of the thread execution I do get the error. On the server side, everything is instance members and it's not using external ressources. I don't get it, I would think that each service call instantiates new instances of the service classes on the server no?

Comment: instantiation os service class is dependent on service definition. In your error there is section which shows server stack trace which makes me beleive that this is something happening at the service level. Can you try debugging the service?

Comment: You are completely right, the exception occured in the service... I had a static property keeping the identity of the user and for some reason this identity was lost between calls of different methods. I've refactored it to keep it static but now I create a new windowsidentity from a copy of the user token. It works. Lesson learned, thanks for your input